# Importing data object from file-to-file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, data-manipulation

I have a .JSON (named dataOut.json) file that looks similar to the following:

```
[
    {
        "scan_type": "nexpose",
        "date_time": "2011-07-18 11:11:11",
        "source_address": "1108",
        "source_lat": "40.581160",
        "source_lng": "-105.184110",
        "dest_address": "11.166.181.0",
        "dest_lat": "30.003880",
        "dest_lng": "-604.800360"
    },
...
]
```

I have a script that seperates the source/destination data points, and places the output in separate files, [here](https://gist.github.com/BrycePearce/c875fb1fab260ff37f77e748a1500117) is my code for doing so.

So here is my problem, I need to export the object variable "scan_type" from the code above, to another .JS file, named jsontonbh.js .

I tried using module exports:

```
//exporting 'scan_type'
obj.forEach(block => {
...
module.exports = {scan_type:block.scan_type};
...
});
```

and then importing it in my [jsontobh.js](https://gist.github.com/BrycePearce/c2bd9120526a7c9dfe32a56a46da3936) file by requiring it, as shown here:

```
let sourceFile = require('./jsonParents.js');

obj.forEach(block => {
    console.log(sourceFile.scan_type)
});
```

this code returns the error "Unexpected end of JSON input"

How can I export this variable *scan_type* from my first script, to my second script?

Comment: Why not just write the `scan_type` to another .JSON file and then read it into the jsontobh.js file?

Comment: @HansStrausl I can probably use that workaround, but I wanted to know if this method was possible. Good idea, thanks!

Comment: If you put some example code and data on github I'll have a look for you.